# How to get the height of a table in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm using this `OFFSET()` function to select an entire column:

`OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,Sheet2!$A$1,100,1)`

Since the table in `Sheet1` may have any height, is there any way to calculate it's height to plug into this formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,Sheet2!$A$1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)
```